# Unable to update Mongo DB conversation collection by using $push

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, socket.io

I have some kind of a hitch in this code. The problem is that when I post a message from `messages.ejs` MongoDB Collection doesn't get updated while in `profile.ejs` all works just fine.

`profile.ejs`

```
            socket.emit('newMessage', {body: message_text, 
                                        type: "Single",
                                        conv_id: users[0].id + "_" + users[1].id,
                                        users: users,
                                        author_name: message__author_name.val(),
                                        author_avatar: message__author_avatar.val(),
                                        author_id: message__author_id.val(),
                                        added: message__date});
```

`messages.ejs`

```
            socket.emit('newMessage', {body: message_text, 
                                        conv_id: urlParams.get('id'),
                                        author_name: '<%= sessionUser.name %>' + ' ' + '<%= sessionUser.lastname %>',
                                        author_avatar: '<%= sessionUser.avatar %>',
                                        author_id: '<%= sessionUser.id %>',
                                        added: message__date});
```

I suppose not all information filled in the request so that there's such kind of a problem, although fields such as avatar, type, subgroup shouldn't be even added when updating Conversation collection.

```
                let query = { id: data.conv_id };
                //Check if such conversation exists
                Conversation.find({}, query).count((err, cnt) => {
                    if(cnt > 0) {

                        //If IDs were found, add new messages to the existing conversation
                        Conversation.updateOne(query, {
                                "$push" : {
                                    messages: [
                                        {
                                            body: data.body,
                                            author: data.author_name,
                                            author_id: data.author_id,
                                            author_avatar: data.author_avatar,
                                            attachments: attachments,
                                            added: data.added
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }, (err) => {
                                if(err) {
                                    throw err;
                                    return;
                                } else {
                                    console.log('Conversation has been updated with new messages');
                                    return;
                                }
                        });
                    } else {
                        //If there's no such IDs, create a new conversation
                        let newMessage = new Conversation({
                            id: data.conv_id,
                            type: data.type,
                            avatar: "defaultConv.png",
                            subgroup: 'all',
                            users: data.users,
                            messages: [
                                {
                                    body: data.body,
                                    author: data.author_name,
                                    author_id: data.author_id,
                                    author_avatar: data.author_avatar,
                                    attachments: attachments,
                                    added: data.added
                                }
                            ]
                        });
                        newMessage.save((err) => {
                            if(err) {
                                console.log(err);
                                return;
                            } else {
                                console.log('Conversation has been created');
                                return;
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
```

Comment: I think the find function expects the query to be first? `Conversation.find(query)`

Comment: I've solved this problem, see my answer down below

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this problem. This all was caused due to my inattention where URL object with get method was placed.

In `messages.ejs` file it was:

```
    // When User has clicked send button
    // Sending Message
    let queryString = window.location.search;
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
    let urlId = urlParams.get('id');

    sendMessage__btn.click(() => {

        ...

        socket.emit('newMessage', {body: message_text, 
                                        conv_id: urlId,
                                        author_name: '<%= sessionUser.name %>' + ' ' + '<%= sessionUser.lastname %>',
                                        author_avatar: '<%= sessionUser.avatar %>',
                                        author_id: '<%= sessionUser.id %>',
                                        added: message__date});
```

Instead of:

```
    sendMessage__btn.click(() => {
        
        // When User has clicked send button
        // Sending Message
        let queryString = window.location.search;
        const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
        let urlId = urlParams.get('id');

        ...

        socket.emit('newMessage', {body: message_text, 
                                        conv_id: urlId,
                                        author_name: '<%= sessionUser.name %>' + ' ' + '<%= sessionUser.lastname %>',
                                        author_avatar: '<%= sessionUser.avatar %>',
                                        author_id: '<%= sessionUser.id %>',
                                        added: message__date});
```

As the result, a variable `urlId` doesn't got updated and return null or incorrect id